# realloc(), lifetime and UB

Tags: c, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior

There's a recent CppCon2016 talk [My Little Optimizer: Undefined Behavior is Magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7entxbQOCc#t=25m56s), which shows the following code (26 mins into the talk). I beautified it a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));
  int* q = realloc(p, sizeof(int));
  *p = 1;
  *q = 2;
  if (p == q)
  {
    printf("%d %d\n", *p, *q);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The code has undefined behavior (p becomes invalid after realloc() even if realloc() returns the same pointer) and when compiled may print not only "2 2", but also "1 2".

What about a slightly modified version of the code?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
  int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));
  uintptr_t ap = (uintptr_t)p;
  int* q = realloc(p, sizeof(int));
  *(int*)ap = 1;
  *q = 2;
  if ((int*)ap == q)
  {
    printf("%d %d\n", *(int*)ap, *q);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Why can I still get "1 2" printed? Does the integer variable ap also somehow become invalid or "tainted"? If so, what's the logic here? Shouldn't ap become "decoupled" from p?

P.S. Added the C++ tag back. This code can be trivially rewritten as C++ and the same question applies in C++ as well. I'm interested in both C and C++.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I did put the C++ tag because this surfaced in a C++ talk (or conference) and there might be some differences between C and C++ (I do not consider myself a C++ guru by any measure).

Comment: There's nothing c++ specific in your question, that's why I removed it.

Comment: Both C and C++ guarantee that if you cast a pointer to another type and back you get the same pointer, if another type is big enough.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can rewrite it as C++ code. The languages are not the same nor is one a strict subset of another.

Comment: @M.M what if I know for a fact that realloc() returns the same pointer?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Not relevant, you're asking about what's specified by a standard which does not include the concept of programmer knowledge external to the program!

Comment: @M.M Rollback as you like, and think it's valid.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ after further consideration I agree with you, there should be a separate question for C++ if OP is interested because the answer is completely different for that langauge!

Comment: @M.M Well, nice to see an agreement. I'm usually not _vandalizing questions_.

Comment: The lifetime of pointers and data and objects and the like differ sharply in detail between C and C++.  There is exceedingly unlikely to be one person capable of giving a good answer to both the C and C++ version of this question.  This is an area where the two languages differ by a large amount.

Comment: I's clearly about C functions, not C++ functions. Just because you can use them from C++, too does not rectify the C++ tag. Otherwise any C++ question using a C functions like a C library would be C, too.

Comment: @Yakk If I get a good answer for one, I may create a dup for the other if we want to give two check marks.

Comment: @Olaf Besides C functions there also are C++ pointers and objects.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Then ask a seperate question. With both tags, I tend to CV as too broad.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Yes, that's why you should make two questions. Anyway, applying Occam's Razor,it should be clear that both versions are doomed. And as M.M. wrote, you cannot rely on getting the same pointer back anyway. Exploiting this specific form of UB is never the way to go.

Comment: Had `*(int*)ap = 1;` been within the `if()` block, the question would have been better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest C standards leave the issue ambiguous. [N2090](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2090.htm) states that the [DR260](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_260.htm) Committee Response

> has not been incorporated in the standard text, and it also leaves many specific questions unclear...

So, it's reasonable to assume that there's, in fact, undefined behavior, even if it's not explicitly documented in the standard proper.

Comment: There's no ambiguity with regard to the program as written in the question--converting `ap` to an `int*` before observing its value gives the compiler room to pretend that conversion of the original pointer to an `intptr_t` yielded a value that no longer matches any pointer in the universe, and that doing anything with `(int*)ap` invokes UB.  If code had compared `ap` to `(uintptr_t)q` and found them equal, the compiler would have no legitimate basis for regarding `(int*)ap` any differently from any other `(int*)` of an integer expression yielding the same value as `(uintptr_t)q`.

Answer (score 5):

As posted, in C, the code has undefined behaviour because `realloc` may return a different block of memory. In this case, `*(int *)ap` will form an invalid pointer.

A more interesting question would be what happens if we change the code so that it attempts to only proceed if the realloc didn't change the block:

```
int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));
uintptr_t ap = (uintptr_t)p;
int* q = realloc(p, sizeof(int));

if ( (uintptr_t)q == ap )
{
    *(int*)ap = 1;
    // ...
}
```

For C2X there is [a proposal N2090](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2090.htm#pointer-provenance-via-integer-types) to specify *pointer provenance* when passed through integer types.

In the current C standard, there are some rules relating to pointer provenance but it does not say what happens to the provenance when the pointer is passed through integer types and back.

Under this proposal, my code would still be undefined behaviour: `ap` gets the same provenance token as `p` had, which becomes an invalid token when the block is freed.  `(int *)ap` is then using a pointer with an invalid provenance.

The proposal seeks to avoid pointer provenance being "hacked around" by intermediate operations with `uintptr_t` and so on. In this case it specifies that `(int *)ap` has exactly the same behaviour as `p`. (Which is undefined even if the block didn't move, since `p` is an invalid pointer after the `realloc` whether or not it physically moved the block).  In the C abstract machine, the intent is that it's not possible to tell whether or not the block was moved by realloc.

### Background on pointer provenance

"Pointer provenance" means an association between pointer values and the memory block that they point to.  If a pointer value points to an object, then other pointer values derived from that value (e.g. by pointer arithmetic) must stay within the bounds of that object.

(Of course, a pointer *variable* may be reassigned to point to a different object - and thereby gain a new provenance - that's not what we're talking about).

This is not something that appears in a compiled executable, but is something that compilers may track during compilation, in order to perform optimizations. Two pointers with different provenances might have the same memory representation (for example, `p` and `q` in the case that the implementation used the same physical memory block).

A simple example of why pointer provenance provides useful optimization opportunities would be the following snippet:

```
char p[8];
int q = 5;

*(p+10) = 123;
printf("%d\n", q);
```

The idea of provenance allows the optimizer to register undefined behaviour on the code `p + 10`, so it could translate this snippet to `puts("5")` for example, even if `q` happens to immediately follow `p` in memory.  (Aside - I wonder if DJ Bernstein's [boringcc](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10772841) compiler would in fact not be able to perform this optimization).

The existing rules about pointer bounds checking (C11 6.5.6/8) do cover this case already, but in more complicated cases they are unclear, hence the N2090 proposal.  For example, `if ( p + 8 == (void *)&q ) *(char *)((uintptr_t)p + 10) = 123;` would, under N2090, still be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the proposal! (I couldn't find it myself)

Comment: `if ( (uintptr_t)q == ap )` --> On a reallocation, AFAIK, `p`, `q` could both point to the same memory, having _equivalent_ values, but yet _different_ bit patterns, so `(uintptr_t)q == ap` could fail in that case.  Not sure if this relates to your provenance discussion.

Comment: @chux I guess you mean that two different integer values for `uintptr_t` may map to the same memory location. I don't think this case would affect the discussion. (And the standard recommends that the `uintptr_t` mapping is natural, so that case shouldn't arise).

Comment: While a subset of C that disallows creation of pointers from arbitrary integers even if the bit patterns happen to match those of valid pointers could be very useful for some applications, there are many more applications where it's necessary to say "I have this bit pattern--give me a pointer to that address, and don't assume you know anything about it".  Many kinds of systems programming require that ability, and if uintptr_t doesn't provide it I'm not sure what purpose the type would really serve (implementations that don't want to provide such an ability don't have to define the type).

Comment: @chux: It would certainly be valid for an implementation to have `(uintptr_t)q` yield a value different from `ap` even if the pointers had the same bit pattern.  On the other hand, given `uintptr_t aq=(uintptr_t)q;` I see no basis whatsoever by which a compiler could report `aq!=ap` unless `aq` and `ap` actually held different values.

Comment: @supercat Agree that is the integer-ized versions of the pointers have the same values then the pointers _must_ point to the same location.  But if the integer versions differ, the equivalence of pointers remains in question.

Comment: @chux: From the point of view of the Standard, once `realloc` returns a non-null value, no meaningful statement can be made about the pointer that used to be known as `p`.  On the other hand, if casting `q` to `uintptr_t` yields 8675309, then casting to `int*` any integer expression yielding 8675309 must yield a pointer equivalent to `q`.  Of course, even if `p==q`, that would still not imply that any pointers which had been accessed using `p` were still valid.  It would have been much more helpful if a `realloc`-like function had included a `mode` parameter which could be used to ask...

Comment: ...that the function adjust an allocation in place if possible,  and report whether or not it had succeeded, but not affect the validity of any existing pointers regardless, and also if, when used in relocation-permitted mode, it could indicate whether it had in fact done anything to invalidate old pointers.  In the absence of such features, being able to determine whether a block has moved is a useful ability, and the notion that programmers shouldn't be entitled to expect quality implementations for a linear-address platforms to support it is silly.

Comment: @M.M: If there is some special construct or directive which programmers are required to use when using pointers in unusual ways, tracking pointer provenance in cases where that construct/directive isn't used could allow useful optimizations (though a better example might be something like `int foo(int x) { struct { char arr[8]; char q; } s; char *p=&s.arr; p[x]=1; s.q=2; return p[x];}`).  My own take is that while it might be reasonable to say that *in the absence of an explicit cast* it might be reasonable to presume that code will only access elements of `arr`, in the presence of a cast...

Comment: ...such an assumption would not be reasonable.  To allow for good performance in cases where a presumption of aliasing might be expensive, there should be a means of casting which indicates that the cast is *only* being used because of syntactic necessity and not to warn the compiler about aliasing.  Rules which require programmers to let the compiler know when they're doing unusual things are fine; rules which simply forbid programmers from doing anything unusual negate the purpose of having a low-level language in the first place.

Comment: @supercat AFAIK, the platform OP's is not  linear-addressed.  Certainly I would expect it to be and certainly it would be nice if integer versions of equivalent but differing pointers to have the same value.  I'd also like `INT_MAX+1` to `be `INT_MIN` and a host of other issues C specifies as UB I would like defined. I am simply providing my best interpretation of what C allows and neither advocating nor critiquing it.

Comment: @supercat `char *p = &s.arr;` is a constraint violation. My take is that `char *p = &s;` allows access to all bytes of `s`, but `char *p = &s.arr[0];`, and `char *p = (char *)&s.arr`, only allow access to `s.arr`. The current standard is unclear when it comes to objects with subobjects though, presumably the C2X papers will specify that more clearly

Comment: @chux: If the integer-ized versions have the same values than the pointer *yielded by casting the integer-ized version of the now defunct pointer* must be usable in the same way as the new pointer.  The integer comparison yields no information about anything except the values of the integers in question and the effects of casting those integers to pointers.

Comment: @M.M: Sorry--skip the ampersand before @s.arr.  While I don't doubt that some compilers would interpret things as you describe, I think the Standard is clear that converting that `char` pointer to a pointer-to-structure type would yield a pointer that's usable to access anything in a structure, and casting that to `char*` should yield a pointer that can also access anything in the structure.  If code receives a pointer that is known to access the first element of a character array at the beginning of some (possibly unknown) struct or union type, and wants a `char*` it can use...

Comment: I probably have written production code like `(char *)&s.q` and expected that pointer to roam through `s`.

Comment: ...to access anything in the enclosing object, I can't think of any more natural way to indicate that than by using an explicit cast to `char*`.  The problem, fundamentally, is that when Dennis Ritchie designed C compilers didn't distinguish between array-element pointers and general memory pointers, and nobody since has bothered to define any syntax to distinguish them. A useful fix which could be added without breaking existing code would be to treat "void" be a type qualifier which, when applied to the target of a pointer, would indicate that a compiler should expect funny business with it.

Comment: I'd rather see new keywords or attributes added, than ascribing new behaviour to existing constructs

Comment: @M.M: In any case, I think you might do well to adjust your example to one where optimizations based on pointer provenance could be sometimes useful but sometimes dangerous, and where a programmer's reasonable expectations might conflict with those of a compiler in the absence of a new syntax to specify what the compiler is and is not allowed to do.

Comment: @M.M: I am very opposed to the idea of changing or removing the meaning of existing code.  What the Standard should do is define directives to specify precise aliasing semantics (writes and reads act upon the underlying bitwise representations of objects), strict semantics (a compiler can assume code won't do any "funny business" without letting the compiler know), and probably some levels in-between, but if code selects "strict" mode, there should be ways of indicating that a pointer might be used in weird ways; since "void*" is pointer to anything, and "void int*` has no other meaning...

Comment: ...using `void` as a qualifier should avoid the need to invent a double-underline constructs while avoiding breaking any existing code.

Comment: @supercat the purpose of my example was to illustrate why pointer provenance exists.. I think an example showing its danger wouldn't make a good case for its existence  ; that sort of example would be better off in a discussion of the details of the proposals for C2X

Comment: @M.M: If your code had been written `p[10]=123;` it would clearly invoke UB unconditionally, and there would be no point trying to optimize it.  If it received some number `x` from elsewhere an assumption that `p[x]=123;`, the code could be useful and the assumption that it won't hit `q` would be 100% justifiable even under the existing Standard.  The concept of provenance becomes useful if it's necessary to do something with `p` besides simply subscripting it.  I am at a loss, though, to see any real-world benefit to tracking provenance through uintptr_t conversions, beyond the fact...

Comment: ...that it would save some compiler writers the trouble of fixing broken behaviors that are presently non-conforming.

Answer (score 1):

The code as given in the original question invokes Undefined Behavior, so a compiler is entitled to do whatever it wants.  Some background on that form of Undefined Behavior is given below.

Clang would behave oddly, however, given code which is similar to yours but does not invoke Undefined Behavior.  Unless one regards certain language in the Standard as meaningless, clang appears to be non-conforming in this regard. Some people would like to change the Standard to make the following invoke UB, thus justifying clang's behavior, but I would regard such proposals as being fundamentally wrongheaded.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uintptr_t gap,gaq;
int test(void)
{
  int x=0;
  uint8_t *p = calloc(4,1);
  uintptr_t ap = (uintptr_t)p;
  uint8_t *q = realloc(p,4);
  // p is no longer valid after this, but ap still holds some number.
  uintptr_t aq = (uintptr_t)q;
  *q=1;
  if (ap == aq)
  {
    x=256;
    // Nothing in the Standard would say that the result of casting a
    // uintptr_t to a pointer is affected by anything other than the
    // numerical value of the uintptr_t in question.  If aq happened
    // to equal e.g. 8675309, then casting any expression equal to
    // 8675309 into an int* should yield the same value as casting aq;
    // since were here, we'd know that ap was also equal to 8675309, and
    // thus that (int*)ap is equivalent to (int*)aq.
    *(uint8_t*)ap = 123;
  }
  gap=ap;
  gaq=aq;
  return *q+x;
}
```

Clang 3.9.0 invoked on godbolt with options `-xc -O3 -pedantic` generates code which will either return 1 or 257 depending upon whether `ap` and `aq` compare equal, even though nothing in the present Standard would allow `ap` to be treated any differently from any other variable of type `uintptr_t` which happens to hold the same value.  The way the code is written, because no outside code is ever entitled to observe `p`, it would have been permissible for the compiler to generate code that set `ap` to any arbitrary value which doesn't equal `aq` and then ignored the comparison altogether, but nothing in the Standard would allow an implementation to do anything other than write the same value to `gap` and `gaq` and return 379 (123+256) or write different values to `gap` and `gaq` and return 1.

**Background on the UB-ness of comparing an invalid pointer to a valid one**

On some processors, attempting to load a pointer into a register will cause the processor to do some validation regarding its validity.  On the 80286, for example, every pointer includes a segment selector and an offset, and loading a segment selector will cause the processor to fetch some information from a table of valid segments.

Some C implementations will load pointers into registers whenever *anything* is done with them, whether or not they will be used to access memory, and some C implementations for the 80286 might invalidate a segment descriptor if the only thing in the corresponding segment is a block of memory that has been freed.  The authors of the C Standard did not wish to require C implementations to expend effort avoiding register loads in cases where pointers are not dereferenced, nor did they wish to require that implementations maintain valid segment descriptors for pointers that had been freed.  The simplest way to imposing either requirement was to refrain from requiring anything in cases where code does anything that could free a pointer and then does anything that could cause the pointer to be loaded into a register.

There are many implementations where loading a pointer into a register would be safe even if the storage occupied thereby had been freed, or which would avoid "trappable" register loads in cases where a pointer was not going to be dereferenced (loading pointers into general-purpose registers for comparison would be cheaper than loading them into segment registers and transferring them to general-purpose registers for comparison), and I see no reason to believe that the authors of the Standard intended that code which targeted exclusively implementations implementations where either of the above should not be able to exploit techniques like:

```
void do_realloc(int new_size)
{
  void *new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size);
  if (!new_ptr) fatal_error;
  if (new_ptr != old_pointer)
    update_pointers();
}
```

in situations where the realloc was very likely to succeed "in-place" (e.g.
because the block was being shrunk) and where it would be possible--but
expensive--to regenerate pointers to things within the allocated storage if
the object ended up being moved.  Nonetheless, because the Standard does not
require any implementations to support such techniques even in cases where
doing so would cost nothing, some implementations (even those where such
support would cost nothing) go out of their way not to provide it.

Answer (score -1):

> *Why can I still get "1 2" printed?*

For the same reason as the original code, the optimizer knows `*p` is invalid and works backwards under that assumption. Why is it invalid? Because...

> J.2 Undefined behavior
>
> 1 The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> The value of a pointer that refers to space deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function is used (7.20.3).

`*p` is invalid. The optimizer knows that `*(int*)ap` is really `*p` so it's also invalid.

Looking at the IR for both the original and your code with `clang -S -O3 -emit-llvm`, they're almost exactly the same. Both hard code `1` and `2` into the `printf`.

```
%7 = tail call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* nonnull getelementptr inbounds ([7 x i8], [7 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32 1, i32 2)
```

Here's your `main` in IR.

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = tail call i8* @malloc(i64 4)
  %2 = tail call i8* @realloc(i8* %1, i64 4)
  %3 = bitcast i8* %2 to i32*
  %4 = bitcast i8* %1 to i32*
  store i32 1, i32* %4, align 4, !tbaa !2
  store i32 2, i32* %3, align 4, !tbaa !2
  %5 = icmp eq i8* %1, %2
  br i1 %5, label %6, label %8

; <label>:6                                       ; preds = %0
  %7 = tail call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* nonnull getelementptr inbounds ([7 x i8], [7 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32 1, i32 2)
  br label %8

; <label>:8                                       ; preds = %6, %0
  ret i32 0
}
```

There's is almost exactly the same, except for a difference in the ordering of the tail calls and bitcasts. This is yours.

```
  %1 = tail call i8* @malloc(i64 4)
  %2 = tail call i8* @realloc(i8* %1, i64 4)
  %3 = bitcast i8* %2 to i32*
  %4 = bitcast i8* %1 to i32*
```

This is theirs.

```
  %1 = tail call i8* @malloc(i64 4)
  %2 = bitcast i8* %1 to i32*
  %3 = tail call i8* @realloc(i8* %1, i64 4)
  %4 = bitcast i8* %3 to i32*
```

Everything else is the same.

---

As mentioned in the talk, the `if` is a red herring. It's only there to illustrate how apparently absurd the behavior is. It's still there in the IR.

```
  %5 = icmp eq i8* %1, %2
  br i1 %5, label %6, label %8
```

---

You can see the optimizer at work if you print out `p`, `q`, and `(int*)ap`. They're all the result of the first malloc.

```
  %1 = tail call i8* @malloc(i64 4)
  ...
  %8 = tail call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* nonnull getelementptr inbounds ([10 x i8], [10 x i8]* @.str.1, i64 0, i64 0), i8* %1, i8* %1, i8* %1)
```

The pointer is fine. It's dereferencing it that's the problem.

Comment: You don't actually explain where UB is in the version with uintptr_t. Care to explain or delete the answer?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I mostly posted this as an extra data point. But I watched the video and my best interpretation is the invalidation of `p` would also apply to its assignment to `ap`. The optimizer would simply remove the assignment to `ap` along with the `if` statement, just like it removed `p`. In other words, assigning an invalid pointer to another variable doesn't wash away its invalidness. If I can figure out how to use LLVM IR I'll check its output.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Ok, completely redid the answer.

Comment: My question is about the language, about why the code in question has UB. You're trying to answer the question by looking at what one specific compiler does, not about why the language permits it to do what it does. If you use my Smaller C compiler, you'll see that the presented code compiled with it prints "2 2" and you can't use that to explain anything. The C standard does not currently address the problem as explained in [DR260](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_260.htm) and [N2090](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2090.htm). Do you see the point?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Do I see the point... not sure? Why the language permits it... [the speaker made the point in the beginning of their talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7entxbQOCc#t=1m43.1s), undefined means "no requirements at all". LLVM chose to interpret that as assuming undefined behavior cannot happen and optimizes accordingly, another compiler might act differently or not optimize as aggressively. That's undefined behavior for you. If you're asking why the C/C++ standards allow so much undefined behavior, I can't answer that.

Comment: For example, when compiled with `clang -g` I get `2 2` but when compiled with `clang -O3` I get `1 2`. It's the llvm optimizer's interpretation of undefined behavior which causes the weirdness. Whereas `gcc` gives `2 2` for both cases.

Comment: I'll try one more time to make it clear. The standard does not provide explicit treatment for the cases when integers (or, more broadly, "bit patterns" as mention in either DR260 or N2090) are involved besides just pointers. That's why I wrote `Does the integer variable ap also somehow become invalid or "tainted"?` in the first place. The question can be rephrased as "Is this a UB? And if so, where does the standard tell us it is? Why should this be the same as in the all pointers case?" However, you're not seeing that there is a problem. You already know that there's a UB. Not helpful.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I think zneak already answered that. "*I would imagine that the integer version remains valid to use. However, you cast it back to a pointer, and this passage says that using a reallocated/freed pointer value is forever UB*" and "*if it can statically determine that you're using the same pointer value, it is well within its authority to flag the UB and do whatever it wants (even though it is my personal opinion that this does nothing but trip honest people).*" It's a shame that answer was deleted, it seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: My opinion is that the standard alone doesn't answer the question but DR260 and N2090 fill in the gaps and let us answer it in a sort of retroactive way.

Comment: If the code had done `uintptr_t aq = (uintptr_t)q` and compared `ap==aq`, how would that have affected the IR?  Nothing in the Standard would allow a `uintptr_t` to behave as anything other than a numeric value, and thus nothing would allow it to be "poisoned" by anything that happened to the pointer it had previously identified.  While the result of the comparison would say nothing meaningful about `q`, I wouldn't see any legitimate basis for a compiler to omit it.  What would appear in the IR to distinguish a comparison between uintptr_t values from a comparison between pointers?

Comment: @supercat As mentioned in the talk, and as you can see from the IR, the comparison is a red herring. It's just there to point out the absurdity of the behavior. The comparison is there, it's the `%5 = icmp eq i8* %1, %2` and `br i1 %5, label %6, label %8`. What happens is the optimizer changes `printf("%d %d\n", *(int*)ap, *(int*)aq);` to `printf("%d %d\n", 1, 2);`

Comment: @Schwern: If the comparison were changed as I describe and printed out `(int*)ap` and `*q` if `ap` and `aq` match, I would see no basis for UB.  A compiler would be free to make `aq` yield a value different from `ap` even if the bitwise representations of `p` and `q` were identical, but if `aq` equaled 8675309, then converting any integer expression equal to 8675309 to ``int*`` would be defined as yielding a pointer equivalent to `q`.

Comment: @supercat Yes, the UB only applies to, to quote C99, "*The value of a pointer that refers to space deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function is used*". If you don't use the integer as a dereferenced pointer there's no UB. Using any of `p`, `q`, `ap`, `aq`, `(int*)ap`, or `(int*)aq` does not trigger the optimizer behavior. What it does do is make `p`, `q`, `(int*)ap`, and `(int*)aq` are all the result of the first `malloc`. You can run `clang -S -O3 -emit-llvm` yourself and play around.

Comment: I did play around, and found that clang is non-conforming in cases where there is no UB.  See my edited answer.

Comment: @supercat Send them a bug report?

Comment: @Schwern: Would you care to look at my example and tell me if I'm missing anything?  I don't think the issue is so much a "bug" as it is a general pattern of clang processing the language its authors want to process, rather than the one defined by the present Standard.  Nothing in the present Standard allows pointer provenance to carry through uintptr_t, but clang behaves in general as though it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126361/discussion-between-schwern-and-supercat).